# How do I troubleshoot port accessibility to allow inbound connections on MacOS?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, connection, port

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced anything like this. IPv4 ports seem blocked. I have tried everything to open a port on my Mac but the port seems blocked.
It's like the only port that can be opened is 22. I have port forwarding setup and the firewall setup as well.

I'm confused why tor inputs work while ip4 and ipv6 don't.

```
         ipv4    ipv6   onion   total   block
in          0       0       5       5
out         9       1       0      10       2
total       9       1       5      15
```

Is there some tools I can use to trace where the port is blocked?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while it's a well formatted question, it is about system administration not Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

Tor is not using the usual ipv4 or ipv6 connexion ports, it use the 9050, 9051 and 9150 ports, it can be why tor is running, maybe the port is blocked by your ISP or a firewall in your network ? you can try using a VPN or a proxy to go arround this problem.

To check your port you gonna need to do this from an external location, here is some on line tool: Nmap Online, Port Scanner Tool, HackerTarget.com